# How can I create an SQL statement that works equally well with MySQL and Sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, mysql-python

The python MySQL interface MySQLdb use `%s` for SQL parameters but SQLite3 uses `?`. Is there a way that I can have a single version of a SQL statement with variable substitution that works with both?

Comment: Don't. Pick one and target its SQL dialect.

Comment: @Shawn that's too hard.

Comment: It's easier than trying to support multiple databases that don't have the same feature set or behaviors.

Comment: @shawn, I'm happy to use a simple subset. I've had nothing but problems using ORMs. But I hear you...

Comment: Yeah, ORMs suck for anything non-trivial.

Comment: @shawn, thanks for that info. I thought it was just me.